# How can I write an arrow on formula of matrix?

Tags: tikz-pgf, math-mode

I have to make a report for mathematics.
I need to show a detail of elementary row operations like the picture below, but I have no idea how to write in tex.
[image: What I would like to do]
It's not necessary to make the arrows red, I just would like to add what is drawn in red.
I considered using `\pmatrix` and tikz, but failed.

Do you know the way to do it? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried [tikzmark](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzmark)?

Comment: Check package [gauss](https://ctan.org/pkg/gauss).

Comment: Have a look at `nicematrix`.